# NoMethodError: undefined method `source' when using Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make it so my users can see their billing history from stripe using web hooks. I'm getting data from stripe for each customer but I'm not getting the card source data.

here's my initializer/stripe.rb file

```
Stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET

class RecordCharges
  def call(event)
    charge = event.data.object
    #Look up the user in our database
    user = User.find_by(stripe_id: charge.customer)
    #Record a charge in our database
    c = user.charges.where(stripe_id: charge.id).first_or_create
    c.update(
      stripe_id: charge.id,
      amount: charge.amount,
      amount_refunded: charge.soruce.amount_refunded,
      card_last4: charge.source.last4,
      card_brand: charge.source.brand,
      card_exp_month: charge.source.exp_month,
      card_exp_year: charge.source.exp_year,
    )


  end
end

StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.subscribe 'charge.succeeded', RecordCharges.new
end
```

Here's the cards_controller.rb

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_after_action :verify_authorized

  def update
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
    subscription = customer.subscriptions.retrieve(current_user.stripe_subscription_id)
    subscription.source = params[:stripeToken]
    subscription.save
    current_user.update(
      card_last4: params[:card_last4],
      card_exp_month: params[:card_exp_month],
      card_exp_year: params[:card_exp_year],
      card_exp_year: params[:card_exp_year],
      card_brand: params[:card_brand]
    )
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, notice: "Successfully updated your card"
  end
end
```

It appears that the controller is working because I'm able to update the user. The problem is that when I do card_brand, card_exp_year etc... are all set to nill.

Here's what I get when I lookup the purchase in the console.

run: event = Stripe::Event.retrieve("event_id")

```
=> #<Stripe::Event:0x3fc6dc914fa0 id=evt_18CFSRGgSrxZ3yXH1ktgY3M6> JSON: {
  "id": "evt_18CFSRGgSrxZ3yXH1ktgY3M6",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2016-03-07",
  "created": 1463519427,
  "data": {"object":{"id":"sub_8TBqDmWv6yFKOd","object":"subscription","application_fee_percent":null,"cancel_at_period_end":false,"canceled_at":null,"created":1463519427,"current_period_end":1466197827,"current_period_start":1463519427,"customer":"cus_8TBqPq3Y9npBz0","discount":null,"ended_at":null,"metadata":{},"plan":{"id":"pro-49","object":"plan","amount":4900,"created":1463398458,"currency":"usd","interval":"month","interval_count":1,"livemode":false,"metadata":{},"name":"Monthly pro-49","statement_descriptor":null,"trial_period_days":null},"quantity":1,"start":1463519427,"status":"active","tax_percent":null,"trial_end":null,"trial_start":null}},
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": "req_8TBqLJDEuitTfN",
  "type": "customer.subscription.created"
}
```

then I look at the object data by running event.data.object

The json looks like this:

```
     => #<Stripe::Subscription:0x3fc6dc9243ec id=sub_8TBqDmWv6yFKOd> JSON: {
  "id": "sub_8TBqDmWv6yFKOd",
  "object": "subscription",
  "application_fee_percent": null,
  "cancel_at_period_end": false,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "created": 1463519427,
  "current_period_end": 1466197827,
  "current_period_start": 1463519427,
  "customer": "cus_8TBqPq3Y9npBz0",
  "discount": null,
  "ended_at": null,
  "metadata": {},
  "plan": {"id":"pro-49","object":"plan","amount":4900,"created":1463398458,"currency":"usd","interval":"month","interval_count":1,"livemode":false,"metadata":{},"name":"Monthly pro-49","statement_descriptor":null,"trial_period_days":null},
  "quantity": 1,
  "start": 1463519427,
  "status": "active",
  "tax_percent": null,
  "trial_end": null,
  "trial_start": null
}
```

Note that the source isn't there. It should have a source object that has all the data I need but for some reason it's not showing up.

furthermore, if I call event.data.object.source I get the no method error... which makes sense since it's not there.

This is my first time integrating stripe so I'm not sure if I missed something in the setup. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Not all the Stripe events contain the same data. For `customer.subscription.created` events, you get the above JSON object. It is just to denote that this customer is now on this subscription.

I think what you're looking for is one for the charge. Check out the `charge.succeeded` webhook. It includes the source object which would be the card used for payment.